# How to convert an int to a datetime?

Tags: c#

I have a date that is converted to int using the following formula:

```
var i = date.Year * 65536 + date.Month * 256 + date.Day;
```

How do I convert the int back to the date?

Comment: It would make more sense to use bitwise operations both ways `var i = (date.Year<<16) + (date.Month << 8) + date.Day;` and inversely `i >> 16`, `i >> 8 & 0xFF`, `i & 0xFF`

Comment: @TheGeneral A cleaner solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems like you are using different bits of an `int` to store the date. The most significant 16 bits are the year. The 8 bits after that is the month, and the least significant 8 bits are the day.

You can therefore use bitwise operations to get the year, month and day:

```
uint unsigned = (uint)i; // cast to uint because we don't want to do an arithmetic shift
uint year = unsigned >> 16;
uint month = (unsigned >> 8) & 0xff;
uint day = unsigned & 0xff;
```

In fact, `i` can also be calculated using bitwise operations:

```
var i = date.Year << 16 | date.Month << 8 | date.Day;
```

Answer (score 2):

This formula writes day, month and year in first, second and third bytes of int. So you basically just need to take these bytes and create DateTime from them:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var i = date.Year * 65536 + date.Month * 256 + date.Day;
var dt = new DateTime(i >> 16, i >> 8 & 0xFF, i & 0xFF);
```